# Need help toggling my blinking function on and off

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my function... It works perfectly, basically it's echoing 100's of results from a main frame.... It is only reason why I'm using this blinking, I need a way to turn it off and on..... any help is appreciated

```
<script>
function blink(f,t,c,n) {
var f; // Function
var t; // Time
var c; // Color
var n; // Next Color
var y; // Test Variable
if (f===undefined) {
    setTimeout('blink("LOCKED",   100,"#004400","#00FF00")',100);
    setTimeout('blink("DISABLED", 300,"#888800","#FFFF00")',300);
    setTimeout('blink("READY",    200,"#004400","#008800")',200);
    setTimeout('blink("MARKEDOUT",500,"#772000","#FFbb00")',500);
}
else {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("chip");
  var len = x.length;
  for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
      y=x[i].title;
      if (x[i].title==f) {
          if (Math.random()>.5){
             x[i].style.backgroundColor=c;
          }
       }
  }  // end chip for loop
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("chipr");
  var len = x.length;
  for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
      y=x[i].style.backgroundColor;
      if (x[i].title==f) {
         if (Math.random()>.5){
             x[i].style.backgroundColor=c;
         }
       }
  }  // end chipr for loop
  y="blink('" + f + "'," + t + ",'" + n + "','" + c + "')" ;
  c="zzz";
  setTimeout(y,t);
  c="xxx";
} // end else
  c="www";
} // end of "blink"
.</script>
```

My HTML code is in two places:

```
<!  One body tag enables blinking, the other does not >
<!body onload="blink();MM_preloadImages('images/gold.png','images/goldset.png')">
<body MM_preloadImages('images/gold.png','images/goldset.png')">
```

and here is the section that light's up...

```
<div class="statcontainer">
<div class="chip"  id="b37:00" style="background-color: <?php echo $cccd0 ['BRD 37']?>" title="<?php echo $ccstat[0]['BRD 37']?>"> </div>
<div class="chip"  id="b37:01" style="background-color: <?php echo $cccd1['BRD 37']?>" title="<?php echo $ccstat[1]['BRD 37']?>"> </div>
<div class="chip"  id="b37:02" style="background-color: <?php echo $cccd2['BRD 37']?>" title="<?php echo $ccstat[2]['BRD 37']?>"> </div>
<div class="chip"  id="b37:03" style="background-color: <?php echo $cccd3['BRD 37']?>" title="<?php echo $ccstat[3]['BRD 37']?>"> </div>
<div class="chipr" id="b37:07" style="background-color: <?php echo $cccd4['BRD 37']?>" title="<?php echo $ccstat[4]['BRD 37']?>"> </div>
<div class="chipr" id="b37:06" style="background-color: <?php echo $cccd5['BRD 37']?>" title="<?php echo $ccstat[5]['BRD 37']?>"> </div>
<div class="chipr" id="b37:05" style="background-color: <?php echo $cccd6  ['BRD 37']?>" title="<?php echo $ccstat[6]['BRD 37']?>"> </div>
<div class="chipr" id="b37:04" style="background-color: <?php echo $cccd7['BRD 37']?>" title="<?php echo $ccstat[7]['BRD 37']?>"> </div>
</div>
```

Then you might need the variable that contains $ccstat

```
<?php
$cccd0 = array();
$ccstat = array();   // two dimensional array to hold status that will be   board-chip status as a title
 if (($handle = fopen($statfile, "r")) !== FALSE)
 {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
{
    if(substr(trim($data[0]), 0, 3) == 'BRD')
    {
        $board = trim($data[0]);
        $temp  = trim($data[2]);
        list($temp,$status)=explode(" ",$temp,2);  // First token (color)  into temp.  Rest of field into status
        $cccd0[ $board ] = $temp;
        $ccstat[0][$board]=$status; // mainjob will display this as a   title on the div i.e. a "tooltip"
    }
    }
  fclose($handle);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What is your HTML code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear a timeout with `window.clearTimeout(myTimeout);` but it needs to be assigned to a variable.

```
// HTML
<span onclick="killLoop();">Cancel blink!</span>
<span onclick="startLoop(f,t,c,n);">Start blink!</span>

// JS
window.myTimeout = false;

startLoop = function (f,t,c,n) {
    if (window.myTimeout === false) blink(f,t,c,n);
}

killLoop = function () {
    if (window.myTimeout !== false) {
        window.clearTimeout(window.myTimeout);
        window.myTimeout = false;
    }
}

function blink(f,t,c,n) {
  ...
  window.myTimeout = setTimeout(y,t);
  ...
}
```